# How do I get all messages on a channel and post to hastebin? discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm idealizing a doubt bot. In view of this, I must explain that at the end of the member's question, the channel must be closed and before that the bot must send a link from hastebin.com with the logs of the created channel.

An example in practice would be: I create the ticket, the channel is created so that only me and the staff can see the channel. I ask and am answered. After having my answer, the channel is closed (deleted). Before being deleted, the bot creates a log and sends it to the hastebin, which stays the same in the print below.

[image]

Please, help me!

edit: I know how to do most of them, but my problem is to get the channel log and post it in hastebin, formatted.

Comment: You probably should break down your problem into smaller problems and ask where you are stuck. You are asking here for a finished solution.  
If you are stuck at getting a Discord bot running. Ask how to run a discord bot. If you are stuck at creating/deleting text channels ask how to create and delete text channels. If you are having problems at retrieving the chat log ask that specifically. For each of those steps you provide the code you've written as well as an error traceback of it not working.

Comment: I know how to do most of them, but my problem is to get the channel log and post it in hastebin, formatted.

Comment: @Amees in this case add the code you tried, what is the exact problem, your data and the desired output. Look at how to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question / ask a new one

Comment: I liked your idea so I'm going to do it. If you want to add me on discord: Eleven_#8917

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after we talk about we really got something here. I updated your code to something more efficiently and I think whatever people that uses discord.js will be able to understand what is going on here.

**Old Code**

```js
    message.channel.fetchMessages().then(messages => {
        console.log(`${messages.size} procuradas.`);
        messages.array().reverse().forEach(msg => {
            console.log(`[${moment(msg.createdTimestamp).format("DD/MM/YYYY - hh:mm:ss a").replace("pm", "PM").replace("am", "AM")}] ` +
            `[${msg.author.username.toString()}]` + ": " + msg.content);
        });
        
    })
```

**New Code**

```js
message.channel.fetchMessages().then(async messages => {
    console.log(`${messages.size} procuradas.`);

    let finalArray = [];

    const putInArray = async (data) => finalArray.push(data);
    const handleTime = (timestamp) => moment(timestamp).format("DD/MM/YYYY - hh:mm:ss a").replace("pm", "PM").replace("am", "AM"); 

    for (const message of messages.array().reverse()) await putInArray(`${handleTime(message.createdTimestamp)} ${message.author.username} : ${message.content}`); 

    console.log(finalArray);
    console.log(finalArray.length);

});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

An update to the accepted answer: the Discord.js package has changed since the answer was written and the new way to fetch messages is with

```
message.channel.messages.fetch().then(...);
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch