# How can I make my code log all things sent in one channel to a text file?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have been trying for days but cant find a way to log all messages into a text file

Here is the code:

```
 module.exports = {
  name: 'log',
  description: "",
  async execute(message, args) {
    const fetched = await client.channels.get("907278968212824164")
    .fetchMessages({limit: 1})
    .then(messages => writeFile('.\MessageLog.txt.')); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get all messages on a channel and post to hastebin? discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60420133/how-do-i-get-all-messages-on-a-channel-and-post-to-hastebin-discord-js)

Answer (score 1):

to get the messages, you need to get the messages from `messageCreate` and use `fs` to write it to your text file.

```js
client.on("messageCreate", message => {
            if (message.channel.id == "id") {
                fs.writeFile("chat.txt", `${message.author}: ${message}`, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        throw err;
                    } 
                })
            }
        }
```

Replace `chat.txt` with the path of your supposed text file. And its done!

Answer (score 0):

Heyo, the best way imo to do this is to start fetching messages in the desired channel then push them to an Array.

You can find the code below i modified from [this answer on another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60460969/14544118)

```js
 module.exports = {
  name: 'log',
  description: "",
  async execute(message, args) {
    const fetched = await client.channels.cache.get("907278968212824164");
    fetched.fetchMessages().then(async messages => {
      console.log(`${messages.size}.`);

      let finalArray = []; // define array

      const putInArray = async (data) => finalArray.push(data); // this will place items in array
      const handleTime = (timestamp) => moment(timestamp).format("DD/MM/YYYY - hh:mm:ss a").replace("pm", "PM").replace("am", "AM"); // this will format the timestamps

      for (const message of messages.array().reverse()) await putInArray(`${handleTime(message.createdTimestamp)} ${message.author.username} : ${message.content}`); 

      console.log(finalArray); // content in array
      console.log(finalArray.length); // length of array

    }).catch(console.error);
  }
}
```

Of course you can change this code around as needed, and add in the "write to text file" where you need it to be.

Comment: thank you for the help but im unsure of what code i need and what i dont need here.

Comment: No worries, I'll edit the code a bit so it better matches what you need. Check back in a little bit and you should see the updated code

Comment: this is annoying not gonna lie, it doesnt have any errors but its not doing anything, im new to programming so im not really sure what the problem is, but what is different is in line 4 it says for both message and args are declared but never read. thats different from my other commands :/